# Determine the dual cone $\mathbb{K}^{*}$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

In the convex optimization book, dual cone of a cone $K$ is:

$$
\mathbb{K}^{*} = \left \{ y^Tx \ge 0 \textrm{ for all } x \in K\right \}
$$
What is dual cone $\mathbb{K}^{*}$ of the follow cone $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}$ ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thank you @José Carlos Santos! I will provide a context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\mathbb K^* = \mathbb K$. Indeed, on one hand $x\in \mathbb K$ for all $y\in \mathbb K$, $\left\langle x, y\right\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n x_iy_i \ge 0.$ and on the other hand, if $x\in \mathbb K^*$ then $x_i = \left\langle x, \underbrace{e_i}_{\in \mathbb K}\right\rangle\ge 0$ so $x\in \mathbb K$.